# What is the most efficient way to update one table's column based on another tables rows?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let assume that we have two tables containing some information about some company stocks as below:

Table 1 (`date_price`): It is consist of price of every single stock of each company in different dates.

```
| Company_ID |    Date   | Stock_Price  |  Market_Value
_______________________________________________________
    ID_1     |  20190111 |     120      |
    ID_2     |  20190111 |      80      |
    .
    .
    .
    ID_N     |  20200411 |     153      |
    ID_1     |  20200412 |     123      |
    ID_2     |  20200412 |      78      |
    .
    .
```

Table 2 (`capital_raises`): It is consist of date of all capital raises of all companies and also the number of stocks of each company before and after of the capital raises.

```
| Company_ID  |  Raise_Date | Before_Raise_Stocks | After_Raise_Stocks |
________________________________________________________________________
      ID_1    |  20190504   |    300,000,000      |    400,000,000
      ID_3    |  20190812   |    800,000,000      |    900,000,000
      ID_1    |  20191210   |    400,000,000      |    450,000,000
      .
      .
      .
```

I want to update first table's `Market_Value` column. To do this I need to multiply price of the stock with the number of stocks of the company on that date.

The question is what's the most efficient way to do this? Is this possible by pure SQL or I need to use another program?

Comment: Do you have to multiply by `Before_Raise_Stocks` or `After_Raise_Stocks`? Also is there a row in `capital_raises` for every `Company_ID` and date?

Comment: If the date is after capital raise, we multiply to the After_Raise_Stocks, and otherwise, we multiply with the Before_Raise_Stocks. But there might be multiple stock raises for a single stocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
update date_price dp
    set Market_Value = dp.Stock_Price * cr.After_Raise_Stocks
    from (select cr.*,
                 lead(RaiseDate) over (partition by Company_Id order by RaiseDate) as next_RaiseDate
          from capital_raises cr
         ) cr
    where cr.Company_Id = dp.Company_Id and
          dp.date >= cr.RaiseDate and
          (cr.next_RaiseDate is null or dp.date < cr.next_RaiseDate)
```

Comment: May I ask you to please a little explanation about the `lead` functionality?

Comment: @Abraham . . . A good place to start is documentation for your database:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner query for that:

```
update date_price dp
set Market_Value = dp.Stock_Price * (
    select After_Raise_Stocks
    from capital_raises cr
    where cr.Raise_Date <= dp.Date
    and cr.Company_ID = dp.Company_ID
    order by cr.Raise_Date desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: You didn't checked for Company_ID. Capital_Raises table contains different companies capital raises info.